# Add stack panel when check box is checked

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to add stack panel dynamically when check box is checked and if check box is unchecked then i want to remove that stack panel. I tried following code.
when i run the program and check the check box nothing is happening.

```
private void bCheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stackpanel = new StackPanel{ Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        stackpanel.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
        stackpanel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);

        var textblockstart = new TextBlock { Text = "loop start time", FontSize = 18, 
                                            Margin = new Thickness(20,20,0,0)};
        var textboxstart = new TextBox { Name = "StartTextBox", Height=27, Width=110, 
                                         Margin = new Thickness(20,10,0,0) };
        var textblockend = new TextBlock { Text = "loop end time", FontSize = 18, 
                                            Margin = new Thickness(20,20,0,0)};
        var textboxend = new TextBox { Name = "EndTextBox", Height=27, Width=110,
                                         Margin = new Thickness(20,10,0,0) };

        stackpanel.Children.Add(textblockstart);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textboxstart);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textblockend);
        stackpanel.Children.Add(textboxend);

    }
```

Comment: The `Check` event is fired only while checking the `CheckBox` and not while Unchecking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create the `StackPanel` in the xaml markup itself with the `Visibility` set to `Collapsed` and just toggle the visibility of the `StackPanel` on the check event of `CheckBox`

Comment: Even better would be to bind to the `IsChecked` property on the `CheckBox`, using the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.